# Add comment link disappears after deleting the last comment on a post on mobile

Tags: bug, comments, mobile-web

To reproduce:

- Find a post with no comments
- Add a comment
- Delete the comment

Now unable to add a comment as the "Add comment" link disappears at the same time as the comment. Refreshing the page restores the link.

I'm using Firefox 68.0.2 on Android 9 (OxygenOS 9.0.7).

This was noticed on an answer on code-golf.SE meta. I've also tested this on this MSO question and the same thing happens, so I'm guessing this affects both questions and answers on all SE sites and meta sites.

[image]

Comment: Unable to reproduce on this post just yet. Using Chrome on Android.

Comment: For me it only happens when there is only 1 comment (I can't reproduce it on this post now that there is an extra comment).

Comment: This has happened to me. Chrome for android, 76